# Grouping objects in a collection list of a collection list on a property

Tags: c#, .net, list

I am busy with analyzing and saving data from my gasmeter.

The data comes from plain text files on a ftp server and i have a console app that puts the data in a database.

Every file has a new header and then a new line of data every 15 minutes. the data gets split up by obis code and every obis code gets a new line in the database. so every 15 minutes 6 new rows are added in the database. and every hour a new header row etc. the detail lines are separated in sequences per 15 minutes.

so the structure is:

header table 1 row > detail table 6 rows per sequence ( for 1 hour 4 sequences of 6 rows)

```
Headerdata
    Detail1 seq=0
    Detail2 seq=0
    Detail3 seq=0
    Detail4 seq=0
    Detail5 seq=0
    Detail6 seq=0
    Detail1 seq=1
    Detail2 seq=1
    Detail3 seq=1
    Detail4 seq=1
    Detail5 seq=1
    Detail6 seq=1
etc....
```

now im trying to do some validation and then write the data to a flat table.
But i only get the first sequence.

I know this has to be easier, but im cracking my head here.

**Update**

I have put most of my code in methods now.
Then the actual question rises:

I have a collection of header data, within each headercollection i have a details collection. each detail has a property sequence.

How can i loop through the details selection and make seperate groups per sequence?
I would like to attach the header of the collection to each group.

Can this be done by linq in the initial query:

```
        public static void getMeterdata(string serial, string date, string interval)
    {
        meterdata = new List<Data_Header>();

        using (var db = new GasMeterDataContext())
        {
            // Query get all headers and their details and put in a list
            meterdata = (from h in db.Data_Header
                         .Where(h => h.Dh_Serial == serial && h.Dh_Timestamp.Contains(date)) 
                         .Include(d => d.Data_Detail)                      
                         orderby h.Dh_Timestamp
                         select h).ToList();
        }

    }
```

Or is making a second linq query on the list the easiest way.

I am very new to C# and Linq.

Comment: Have you debugged into this to inspect what you have at each point in execution? Do you mean that `maxDetailSequences` is always 1?

Comment: 1- create some methods, everything in one method? When you do that maybe you some perspective. 2 - what is the question?

Comment: I have updated my code using methods. i also updated the question. I think handling this in the initial query is the best solution, or am i wrong?